# Can someone explain to me what part of my code causes *** glibc detected *** ./a2: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++

I've have been trying to figure this out for a while now and decided it was time for some outside perspective. I have googled as much as possible and from what I read on similar problems this (I think) has something to do with my allocating less memory than is required. I have gone over my code many times and cannot find where my mistake is.

My professor has wrote a print function and the problem only occurs when that function is called so I have narrowed down my search to this function I wrote.

```
IntStore& IntStore::operator=(const IntStore& rhs)
{
   if(this != &rhs)
   {
      int* newData = new int[rhs.capacity];
      int* newFreq = new int[rhs.capacity];
      for(int i=0; i < rhs.used; i++)
      {
        newData[i] = rhs.data[i];
        newFreq[i] = rhs.freq[i];
      }
      delete [] data;
      delete [] freq;
      data = newData; 
      freq = newFreq;
      capacity = rhs.capacity;
      used = rhs.used;
   }
   return *this;      
}
```

His Print Function reads:

```
void print_to_cout(IntStore src)
{
   // NOTE:
   // - first for-loop below looks silly but is purposely added
   // - don't try to remove/disable when doing the assignment
   // - Why is it added?
   for (int i = 1; i < 2; ++i)
   {
      src = src;
      IntStore copy1;
      copy1 = src;
   }

   int countDist = src.countDistinct();
   for (int i = 1; i <= countDist; ++i)
      cout << setw(5) << src.valAt(i);
   cout << endl;
   cout << "        (freq)";
   for (int i = 1; i <= countDist; ++i)
      cout << setw(5) << src.freqAt(i);
   cout << endl;
}
```

When I run the program this is what I get back:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a2: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000005714010 ***
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

I am including the constructors to shows more specific portions of the code to help with my question. As for the print function. I am not sure why it is written the way it is. Everything in the main cpp file was created by the professor and was not to be edited. The only editing we did was to the Instore.cpp file. The header was also pre-made.

```
#include "IntStore.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

void IntStore::resize(int new_capacity)
{
   if(new_capacity < used)
     new_capacity = used;
   if(new_capacity < 1)
     new_capacity = 1;
   capacity = new_capacity;
   int* newData = new int[capacity];
   int* newFreq = new int[capacity];
   for(int i=0; i < used; i++)
   {
       newData[i] = data[i];
       newFreq[i] = freq[i];
   }
   delete [] data;
   delete [] freq;
   data = newData;
   freq = newFreq;
}

IntStore::IntStore(int init_capacity) : capacity(init_capacity), used(0)
{
   if(capacity < 1)
     capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
   data = new int(capacity);
   freq = new int(capacity);
}

IntStore::IntStore(const IntStore& src) : capacity(src.capacity),
                                                  used(src.used)
{
   data = new int(capacity);
   freq = new int(capacity);
   for(int i = 0; i < used; i++)
   {
     data[i] = src.data[i];
     freq[i] = src.freq[i];
   }
}

IntStore::~IntStore()
{
   delete [] data;
   delete [] freq;
}
```

This is the case for the print function:

```
  case 'p': case 'P':
     objectNum = get_object_num();
     switch (objectNum)
     {
     case 1:
        if ( is1.empty() )
           cout << "   is1: (empty)" << endl;
        else
        {
           cout << "   is1: (data)";
           print_to_cout(is1);
        }
        break;
     case 2:
        if ( is2.empty() )
           cout << "   is2: (empty)" << endl;
        else
        {
           cout << "   is2: (data)";
           print_to_cout(is2);
        }
        break;
     case 3:
        if ( is3.empty() )
           cout << "   is3: (empty)" << endl;
        else
        {
           cout << "   is3: (data)";
           print_to_cout(is3);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Does IntStore's constructor initialize data and freq to 0?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` for `IntStore::data` and `IntStore::freq`? If this class is given by your professor, tell that to them ;)

Comment: Why are'nt you passing src in print_to_cout function by refrence??

Comment: The answer must be in your destructor's code

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze no because in the long aspect the values of the arrays do not matter in determining the contents. Only that which is 'used' according to the teacher. Everything else is irrelevant. The array is only traversed through (used - 1) which is where the values occur up to.

Comment: I'm not talking about the contents. I'm talking about the values of the pointers.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze no I did not. I did in my last program and he took off because of one of his Invariants which is also on this one:

// (6) We DON'T care what is stored in any of the array elements
//     from data[used] through data[capacity - 1], and
//     from freq[used] through freq[capacity - 1].

Comment: I think you don't understand the point. If those 2 pointers (`data` and `freq`) aren't initialized to 0 and are left to have whatever garbage happens to be in memory where they are located, then when your `operator=` tries to `delete[]` them, it can cause a crash or memory corruption.

Comment: Okay I'll try something.

Comment: Nope the crash still occurs even when I initialize in all the functions required.

Comment: wow, I figured it out... I intialized all my points like so:
data = new int(capacity) ------Instead of data = new int[capacity]

Answer (score 1):

In your copy constructor you have `new int(capacity)` where you should have `new int[capacity]`. These are not the same thing at all.

You might consider using the copy and swap idiom for your assignment operator - what you have is mostly correct but rather horrible, and could be a lot shorter and simpler.